# TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am calling async method with ***KeyValueStorage***, I imported KeyValueStorage from "react-native-key-value-storage" but don't know whats wrong.

```
   import KeyValueStorage from "react-native-key-value-storage"

    onsuccessLogin =async  () => {
        try {
          await KeyValueStorage.set("userId", data.userId);
          await KeyValueStorage.set("token", data.token);
          Actions.drawerMenu();
        } catch(error) {
            // Handle error
            console.log("Login-Error",error);
        }
      };
```

Comment: try `setItem` instead of `set`.

Comment: why using keyvalue storage when you have async storage available in react native!!!!

Comment: setItem is available for AsyncStorage @DavidGildour!

Comment: please use AsyncStorage which is developed by react native community itself. It's syntax is much easier. just AsyncStorage.getItem() and AsyncStorage.setItem()

Comment: Actually i just imported project and newbie in react native. let me try with AsyncStorage Thank you guys @GauravRoy ,abhikumar22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) instead of KeyValueStorage it is same as you are using .

But you cannot pass integer type value in this you have to convert them into string.

and it is simple .

**await AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', '' + UserId + '');**

where ***userId*** is the key and the  **UserId**  is the integer type value and we use '' to convert the inner value into the string.

Hope it will help you and save your time as i wasted two days in passing integer type value in AsyncStorage.